# How to change the output of view(response) in scrapy shell to open in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, scrapy

When I type in `view(response)` in the Scrapy shell, the output opens in Visual Studio Code instead of Chrome, as it used to. How can I fix this?

I am working on windows. I found the `bashrc` file (as a result of my researches) and appended this code to it:

```
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

That didn't change anything. Then I removed my `vitual-workspace` and recreated it to reinstall Scrapy (as a result of another suggestion to fix this problem) but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43300353/9003106), internally the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) package is used which uses your default configured browser to open the response. So set Google Chrome to be your default webbrowser in the windows settings.
For windows 10: [Start -> Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs)